# encode the merged XML file

Tags: java, xml

i am using the answer mentioned in the below link to merge XML files
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10760236/1643087
but the output files seems to be missing the encoding

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<DataFile>
    <Contact id="1" time="13vsxv:01" KeyCd="cxcEfsd191cxzcate="2012-11-19"><Name><Title>01</Title><FirstName>Chrcxzcan</FirstName><LastName>methot</LastName></Name><Address><Street>9xcz</Street><City>Repentigny</City><State>QC</State><Zip>J5Y1c9</Zip></Address><ContactInfo><Email>ancxcec@ucxcet</Email><EvePhone>4fds277</EvePhone></ContactInfo><Language><Lang>0cxc</Lang></Language></Contact>
    <Contact id="2" time="13:02:01" KeyCd="0dasdEC201sda3dad000036" date="2012-11-19">....</Contact>
    .............
</DataFile>
```

can anybody tell me how to set encoding="ISO-8859-1"
and instead of
    XMLInputFactory xmlInFactory = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
i have used
       XMLInputFactory xmlInFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();

Comment: You should link to the answer in the above, not the question (see the 'share' button for each answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating the document, you pass in the encoding you want to use.

```
xmlEventFactory.createStartDocument("ISO-8859-1");
```

Answer (score 0):

On the marshaller, you set the property for the encoding.

```
m.setEncoding("jaxb.encoding", "ISO-8859-1");
```